# С++ Проблемки с задачкой

Tags: c++

***Помогите решить проблему:
Ввожу кол-во задач больше 2 и у меня начинается бесконечный цикл. Я только обучаюсь, но не пойму в чем проблема в этой ситуации.

---

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int n;
    int i;
    struct land
    { 
        char name[20];
        int time;
        char task[200];
    }
    s[n];

    cout<<"Добро пожаловать в ежедневник!"<<endl;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("task.txt");
    if (fout){
    cout<< "Предлагаем написать задачи на сегодня: "<<endl;
    cout<< "Введите коло-во задач:"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    {
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        cout<<" Имя: ";
        cin>> s[i].name;
        cout<<" Время: ";
        cin>> s[i].time;
        cout<<" Задача: ";
        cin>>s[i].task; 
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        fout << "Имя: " << s[i].name <<endl;
        fout << "Время: " << s[i].time <<endl;
        fout << "Задача: " << s[i].task <<endl;     
    }
    }
    cout<<"Успех! Задачи успешно записаны!"<<endl;
    fout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не стоит пытаться впихнуть в вопрос все свои проблемы. Выделите отдельно каждую задачу и попробуйте её решить. Если не получится, создайте [mcve] и оформите отдельным вопросом на сайте. В текущем виде ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас сделаю

Comment: `... char task[200];
}
s[n];` - чему в этом месте равно `n`?

Comment: Для записи данных, у меня же несколько раз будет записываться данные. И это можно сказать "номерация  для записи данных". Я думал создать другую переменную, но выводит "Segmentation fault".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Структура задачи
struct Task
{
    std::string name;
    std::string details;
    std::string time;
};

// Тип действий
enum ActionType
{
    NOT_SELECTED = 0,
    VIEW_TASKS = 1,
    CREATE_NEW_TASKS = 2,
    DELETE_TASKS = 3,
    APPEND_TASKS = 4,
    EXIT = 5
};

// Добавить задачи
ActionType createNewTasks(bool recreate = false);

// Просмотр задач
ActionType viewTasks();

// Удалить задачи
ActionType deleteTasks();

// Выбрать действие
ActionType selectAction();

// Есть ли файл
bool fileExists(const std::string& name){
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    return f.good();
}

/**
 * \brief Точка входа
 * \param argc Кол-во аргументов
 * \param argv Аргументы
 * \return 
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Текущее действие (не выбрано)
    ActionType action = ActionType::NOT_SELECTED;

    // Локаль
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    std::cout << "Добро пожаловать в ежедневник!" << std::endl;

    // Если файла нет - действие "новые задачи"
    if (!fileExists("tasks.txt")) action = ActionType::CREATE_NEW_TASKS;

    // Вечный цикл
    while (true)
    {
        // В зависимости от того, какое выбрано действие
        switch(action)
        {
        case ActionType::EXIT:
            return 0;
        case ActionType::NOT_SELECTED:
            action = selectAction();
            break;
        case ActionType::CREATE_NEW_TASKS:
            action = createNewTasks(true);
            break;
        case ActionType::APPEND_TASKS:
            action = createNewTasks(false);
            break;
        case ActionType::DELETE_TASKS:
            action = deleteTasks();
            break;;
        case ActionType::VIEW_TASKS:
            action = viewTasks();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Добавить задачи
ActionType createNewTasks(bool recreate)
{
    // Открытие файла для записи
    // Либо затираем все, либо дописываем (в зависимости от recreate)
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("tasks.txt", recreate ? std::fstream::out : std::fstream::app);

    // Ввод кол-ва
    int qnt;
    std::cout << "Введите кол-во задач : ";
    std::cin >> qnt;
    std::cin.ignore();

    //Ввод задач
    for(int i = 0; i < qnt; i++)
    {
        Task t;
        std::cout << "Введите название задачи # " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, t.name);
        std::cout << "Введите детали задачи # " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, t.details);
        std::cout << "Введите время задачи # " << i + 1 << ": ";
        std::getline(std::cin, t.time);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        f << t.name << " | " << t.details << " | " << t.time << std::endl;
    }

    // Закрыть
    f.close();
    return ActionType::NOT_SELECTED;
}

// Просмотр задач
ActionType viewTasks()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file("tasks.txt");
    if (file.is_open()){
        while (getline(file, line)){
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return ActionType::NOT_SELECTED;
}

// Удалить задачи
ActionType deleteTasks()
{
    // Открытие файла для записи c затиранием сожержимого
    std::fstream f;
    f.open("tasks.txt", std::fstream::out);
    f.close();

    return ActionType::NOT_SELECTED;
}

// Выбрать действие
ActionType selectAction()
{
    int actionType;

    std::cout << "1 - показать задачи" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2 - новые задачи" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3 - удалить задачи" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4 - добавить задачи" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5 - выход" << std::endl;
    cin >> actionType;

    actionType = std::min(actionType, 5);
    actionType = std::max(actionType, 0);

    return static_cast<ActionType>(actionType);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но сложновато( Я  некоторые части понимаю, но много ещё нет, ООП только начинаю учить.

Comment: @Alex , пишите, если что непонятно по коду, поясню

Comment: ActionType  это название верно?) И не много не понял код с кейсами и почему  в вводе задач вы  писали " i + 1"(Не понимаю это). Вот это тоже Task t; )) Извините что вас беспокою и спрашиваю такие простые вопросы.

Comment: Так же это не понимаю как появилось, "ActionType action", это ж константа верно? Просто не вижу чтоб вы её объявили с начала чтоб использовать.

Comment: @Alex, ActionType - это перечисляемый тип, а его варианты описаны между фигурными скобками. По скольку у нас есть несколько типов действий, и программа постоянно работает (вечный цикл), нужно отслеживать какое имено действие сейчас обрабатывается (это происходит в switch блоке). Для простоты можете заменить переменную ActionType action на обычную int переменную, сути это не изменит. Я использовал enum, так как посчитал что это более наглядно.

Comment: @Alex, насчет "Task t" - у нас есть структура Task, она описана выше (содержит 3 строковых поля). Когда нужно - мы создаем ее объект (подобно тому, как объявляем переменные, Task - тип, t - название переменной). Затем заполняем ее поля, а затем используем данные из нее (в вашем первоначальном вопросе, если не ошибаюсь, было условие - использовать структуру)

Comment: Понял,спасибо большое) А можете подсказать в моём коде как правильно чистить область памяти. Хочу и свой код решить и главное знаю проблему и каким способ решить,но опыта не хватает(

Comment: Проблема в таком: У меня забивается область памяти из за чего начинается "вечный цикл", надо после каждой записи чистить её, с помощью delete [] s; . Но я не знаю как это правильно сделать ввиде кода.

Comment: @Alex, я просто после ввода n добавил инициализацию вашего массива задач - land* s = new land[n]; и ваш код заработал.Перед этим конечно же удалил s[n] ввреху. Освобождать память нужно после того, как вы закончили с ней работать (не в цикле!), и точно знаете что ваш массив s больше не будет нужен. Если же после операции с вашим динамическим массивом программа завершается - то память процесса будет автоматически очищена, так что об этом можно не волноваться (но хорошим тоном будет все очистить явно, то есть сделать delete[] s;)

Comment: main.cpp:116:7: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
 land* s = new land[n];
       ^
main.cpp:116:15: error: expected type-specifier before ‘land’
 land* s = new land[n];

Comment: У меня такое выводит, всё делал как вы сказали.

Comment: Да и кстати, а что такое land, я о нём первый раз слышу)

Comment: @Alex, а зачем вы отделяете область видимости вокруг циклов (заключаете оба цикла в фигурные скобки)? land - это в вашем коде вы так назвали структуру задачи. Не знаю почему именно так, вам лучше знать..

Comment: Точно) Я забыл что я потом сменил название структуры) Спасибо большое) Теперь всё работает)

Answer (score 1):

> warning: variable 'n' is uninitialized when used here
>
> [-Wuninitialized] s[n]; note: initialize the
>
> variable 'n' to silence this warning int n;
>   1 warning generated.

Вот, что выводит компилятор.

Для статических массивов **n** должно быть константным значением, либо, если это динамический массив, то **n** вводится, и пример имеет вид :

```
 int *s= new int[n];
```

Где ***s** -указатель на область памяти размером **n**

У вас же не задан ни один из перечисленных вариантов

Если вы хотите занять участок памяти, а потом использовать снова этот же участок памяти, то его для начало необходимо очистить

```
delete[] s;
```

А после уже снова использовать

Comment: Понял, в этом случае мне нужно в цикле вставить delete[] s; И после каждой записи оно будет чистить эту область памяти, верно?

Comment: **delete[] s** занимается тем, что освобождает занимаемую область памяти.
Только аккуратнее, особенно в будущем при использовании конструкторов и деструкторов, потому что память может затереться несколько раз, что совсем не хорошо

Comment: Не получается((